# How to type python file in cmd?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-mining

I have completed a py file as follow:

```
import re

file = open('/Path/text1.txt')

word = 'summer flowers'

try : 

   flag = 0

   for line in file :

       lines = line.lower()

       x=re.findall('.*'+word+'\s.*',lines)

       if len(x)>0:

           flag =1

           print line

       else:

           flag = flag

   if flag == 0:

       print 'No match!'

except:

    print 'No enough arguments!'
```

I have saved above py file as test1.py. My question is that: How to type above code in the cmd line?

e.g. I hope to input the code:
" **test1.py 'summer flowers', text1.txt** " 
in the cmd to execute above code

where test1.py is the file name of the py file, 'summer flowers' is the key word I want to search and match in the txt file and text1.txt is the txt file name.

Comment: `python.exe your_file.py 'summer flowers', text1.txt` That's it.

Comment: @RedX your comment assumes windows os.  That probably isn't correct considering the path the OP is using

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
import sys 

file = sys.argv[2]
word = sys.argv[1]

try : 

   flag = 0

   for line in file :

       lines = line.lower()

       x=re.findall('.*'+word+'\s.*',lines)

       if len(x)>0:

           flag =1

           printline

       else:

           flag = flag

   if flag == 0:

       print 'No match!'

except:

    print 'No enough arguments!'
```

Use `sys` to deal with command line stuff. `sys.argv` returns a list of the arguments from the command line and since you wanted to run it in cmd line use `python script_name.py keyword filename` don't need quotes for single words or commas. Also note `sys.argv[0]` is reserved for the file name so `sys.argv` returns `['script_name.py', 'keyword', 'filename']` if you ran the command above.

Edit:

Like the comment says if you want a phrase instead of a word you can use `quotes` in the commend line so:

`python script_name.py "my phrase" filename`

will return in `sys.argv` as `['script_name.py', 'my phrase', 'filename']`

Comment: You do need quotes for an input phrase containing spaces,  though

Comment: @cricket_007 True that, but since it was a keyword he was searching I thought maybe just a single word would do, I'll edit. Thanks

Comment: @Galor Feel free to accept any given answer on this site when you are satisfy with the answer (the check mark under the scoring).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sys` module. Specifically, [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

From the docs:

> sys.argv
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.